# fstab won't mount SMB/CIFS share in Ubuntu 14.04 (after upgrade from 12.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, cifs, smb

I have a NAS network file server which under Ubuntu 12.04LTS I used to automatically mount using the following entry in my `fstab` file:

```
//nas-A0-B9-AF/public /opt/Z cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

I upgraded to 14.04 (big mistake) and the share does not mount! Nothing has changed on the server side. 
Although I can manually mount the partition by the following command, I no longer have read write access

```
sudo mount  192.168.1.103:/c/public /opt/Z
```

I hope someone can help me; this is causing me a great deal of stress and lot of wasted time.

Just one thing: During the upgrade process I opted for my samba configuration to be left as it was under 12.04LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through an insane number of trial and error experiments and scouring different discussion fora (not forums, fora) I found the following works

//192.168.1.103/public /opt/Z cifs username=,password=,_netdev,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0

I have no idea what sec=ntlm means, but it appears to solve my problem. Could someone please do a post-mortem on this for me? 
(Neon_overload: Thank you for trying to help anyway.)

Comment: +1 thanks, I am grateful not having to do all your research for myself. This worked.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while, however, I'd like to share what worked for me. It turns out that installing package 'cifs-utils' was all I needed to add. I had sec=ntlm, but still received an error stating wrong fs type, bad superblock.

Installing cifs-utils fixed the issue and mount -a worked fine after that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting the "sec=ntlm" security option. I have been trying for days to get my new version of Ubuntu to automount a CIFS share. According to the mount.cifs man page, the default, in kernels prior to 3.8, was "sec=ntlm". The new default is "sec=ntlmssp". The man page explains the 9 different security mode options.

Answer (score 0):

> During the upgrade process I opted for my samba configuration to be left as it was under 12.04LTS.

Without having looked into this very deeply, this could be the issue. Sometimes software changes enough between releases to require changes to the configuration files for it to continue to work.

When you're given the opportunity to keep the old configuration file you should have been given the chance to see a comparison or diff of the changes between your version and the new version. You could selectively apply the new version if you wanted.

You may be able to fix this with a `sudo dpkg-reconfigure samba-common` or a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall samba-common` (I believe it's the samba-common package that houses the config files but I'm not certain).  Take note of any custom configuration so you can re-apply it later if necessary.

Comment: I tried this, but to no effect. I issuse sudo mount -a, but I get 
mount error(95): operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page

Comment: I edited my answer a couple of times as I wasn't certain which package to reconfigure, so do re-read.  If that still doesn't work I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Yeah, done those too, no effect.